# python lambda functions behavior

Tags: python, lambda

I am having a hard time understanding the behavior of these lambda functions in python 3.10.0

I am trying to define the `NOT` logical operator from lambda calculus (see, e.g., the definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Logic_and_predicates)
The following implementation is correct:

```
In [1]: TRUE  = lambda a: lambda b: a
   ...: FALSE = lambda a: lambda b: b
   ...: NOT = lambda a: a(FALSE)(TRUE)
   ...: assert NOT(FALSE) == TRUE
```

However, when I try and do a literal substitution either for `FALSE` or `TRUE`, the code fails

```
In [2]: NOT1 = lambda a: a(FALSE)(lambda a: lambda b: a)
   ...: assert NOT1(FALSE) == TRUE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 NOT1 = lambda a: a(FALSE)(lambda a: lambda b: a)
----> 2 assert NOT1(FALSE) == TRUE

AssertionError:
```

Can anybody explain me why this happens?

Comment: `a = lambda x: x; b = lambda x: x; assert a == b` also fails.  I imagine that this is because of how `__eq__` is implemented for python functions, although I do not know the details.

Comment: very good observation @hilberts_drinking_problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python function `==` works by object identity. (Trying to implement it any other way ranges from "painfully inconsistent" to "[plain impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)".) You have created another function with the same behavior as your `NOT` function, but it is not the same function object, so `==` says they're not equal.

Answer (score 3):

The main principle is that **every invocation of `lambda` creates a new function**.

Your first cell is exactly this:

```
def TRUE(a):
    def _inner(b):
        return a
    return _inner

def FALSE(a):
    def _inner(b):
        return b
    return _inner

def NOT(a):
    return a(FALSE)(TRUE)
```

Executing `NOT(FALSE)` results in `FALSE(FALSE)(TRUE)` results in `FALSE._inner(TRUE)` returning TRUE, **a function**.

Now your second cell, executing `NOT1(FALSE)` results in `FALSE(FALSE)(lambda...)` results in `FALSE._inner(lambda...)` returning `lambda...`, another function **but not the same function defined in `TRUE`**. Remember the principle I said earlier? That `lambda` statement created a **new function**.

The `==` operator when comparing two functions does not concern itself with the *contents* of the function. It only concerns itself whether the items being compared are pointing to the *exact same function in memory*. But since `TRUE` and `lambda...` are two separate functions -- at different memory locations even if the contents are the same -- then `==` comparison fails.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who clarified the issue with the `==` operator.

I have tried to understand where exactly the two functions are different.
Let's start with the simpler example

```
In [18]: id(f)
Out[18]: 140465987909328

In [19]: id(g)
Out[19]: 140465990159088

In [20]: assert f==g
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 assert f==g

AssertionError:
```

clearly the two objects have different `id`s

```
In [21]: id(f)
Out[21]: 140465987909328

In [22]: id(g)
Out[22]: 140465990159088
```

what is less obvious to me is that they do have different hash values

```
In [23]: f.__hash__()
Out[23]: 8779124244333

In [24]: g.__hash__()
Out[24]: 8779124384943
```

The equivalence test that I need can be done on the `__code__.co_code` function attribute.

```
In [25]: f.__code__.co_code
Out[25]: b'|\x00S\x00'

In [26]: g.__code__.co_code
Out[26]: b'|\x00S\x00'

In [27]: assert f.__code__.co_code == g.__code__.co_code
```

I was curious, however, where exactly the two function objectss differ.
Looking at the methods and attributes of `__code__`, we have

```
In [28]: dir(f.__code__)
Out[28]: 
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'co_argcount',
 'co_cellvars',
 'co_code',
 'co_consts',
 'co_filename',
 'co_firstlineno',
 'co_flags',
 'co_freevars',
 'co_kwonlyargcount',
 'co_lines',
 'co_linetable',
 'co_lnotab',
 'co_name',
 'co_names',
 'co_nlocals',
 'co_posonlyargcount',
 'co_stacksize',
 'co_varnames',
 'replace']
```

So we try and verify where

```
In [29]: L = [x for x in dir(f.__code__) if x.startswith('co_')]

In [29]: for x in L:
   ...:     print(f"{x:20s}", getattr(f.__code__,x)==getattr(g.__code__,x))
   ...: 
co_argcount          True
co_cellvars          True
co_code              True
co_consts            True
co_filename          False
co_firstlineno       True
co_flags             True
co_freevars          True
co_kwonlyargcount    True
co_lines             False
co_linetable         True
co_lnotab            True
co_name              True
co_names             True
co_nlocals           True
co_posonlyargcount   True
co_stacksize         True
co_varnames          True
```

The only fields that are actually different are `co_filename` and `co_lines()`:

```
In [30]: f.__code__.co_filename, g.__code__.co_filename
Out[30]: ('<ipython-input-1-242f7af8e2bb>', '<ipython-input-2-a597939a9a2e>')

In [31]: f.__code__.co_lines()
Out[31]: <line_iterator at 0x7f10948790c0>

In [32]: g.__code__.co_lines()
Out[32]: <line_iterator at 0x7f10945178c0>

In [33]: list(f.__code__.co_lines())
Out[33]: [(0, 4, 1)]

In [34]: list(g.__code__.co_lines())
Out[34]: [(0, 4, 1)]
```

The `co_filename` field cannot be changed:

```
In [35]: f.__code__.co_filename = 'something_else'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 1
----> 1 f.__code__.co_filename = 'something_else'

AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

It seems to me that if the only things that are actually different are these two fields.

Interestingly enough, there is a case for which two lambda functions with different variable names should also be considered the same:

```
In [40]: f = lambda x:x

In [41]: g = lambda y:y

In [42]: f.__code__.co_code
Out[42]: b'|\x00S\x00'

In [43]: g.__code__.co_code
Out[43]: b'|\x00S\x00'
```

and in fact they are, as far as the `co_code` is concerned.

In conclusion, I think that there could be an argument for introducing an `equivalence` operator for functions, different than the `__eq__` operator, maybe something with a syntax `~=`, which does not appear to have been taken yet. Your thoughts?

Comment: Why do you even need a new comparison operator to compare two functions? Creating an operator use only worth it if there are many use cases that demands it. For your use case, just compare `co_code` and be done with it